# QList of pointers, append causes run time error

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qlist

I need to append items from one `QList` to another `QList` almost like a JS / PHP array filter. Here is the gist of the function:

```
QList<Stock*>* list1;
QList<Stock*>* list2;

list1->append(new Confectionery("Sweet", 1,1));
//Confectionery is a subclass of Stock

for(int i = 0; i < list1->size(); i++){
    list2->append(list1->at(i));
}
```

However I get a run time error every time I run the above, most probably a seg fault, but I don't know how to to verify or fix my suspicion.

I've tried:

1. Not QList pointers:

   ```
   QList<Stock*> list1;
   QList<Stock*> list2;
   ```
2. Initializing the QLists before use:

   ```
   QList<Stock*>* list1 = new QList<Stock*>();
   QList<Stock*>* list2 = new QList<Stock*>();
   ```

Comment: Think very carefully about what a pointer is.

Comment: I guess a pointer is a memory address, but I don't know why would a the function crash when you add another memory address to a QList?

Comment: @FranB You have no `QList` here, just a dangling pointer with `QList<Stock*>*` type.

Comment: Return a QList<> not a QList<>*

Comment: Did you initialize list1 and list2? ... You know, like `QList<Stock*>* list1 = new QList<Stock*>();` ?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately same problem - but I have updated the question.

Comment: You need to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem. It's difficult to help when the problem keeps changing.

Comment: @FranB Why do you use raw pointers at all?

Comment: I have been provided with an expected interface, I am trying to make the requested interface work.

Comment: If you initialized your lists, there is nothing wrong with the current code. Although you should show that to avoid confusion.

Comment: In your loop I would use a range based for loop or a Qt foreach. However your code should work as it is.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, the issue is with me trying to use pointers instead of just simple QList instances. I got it to work thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using:

```
QList<Stock*>* list1;
QList<Stock*>* list2;
```

You should use:

```
QList<Stock*> list1;
QList<Stock*> list2;
```

And finally to append you use:

```
list2.append(list1[i]);
```